# List item version history shows only 15 changed columns in Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, sharepoint-online

When looking at the version history of a list item in Sharepoint Online, for each version it shows the columns that were changed in that version. Unfortunately it only shows the first 15 columns that have been changed then just displays some static text of "(more...)".

Is there anyway to see a full list of all the columns and values that were changed rather than just the first 15? I don't know if there is another way, in sharepoint server I used to do by increasing in Versions.aspx page in TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS directory the 15 value in this expression: <% if (numChanges <= 15) %> but now I don't know how to access the layout files.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In the SharePoint Online, it is the default design. And there is no option to change it. You should click View to see all columns.

[image]

Comment: I can do that with the latest version, and what about previous versions? As all the fields that have been modified do not appear, I cannot know the changes in the item. 

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You also could click View to see all columns in previous versions.